# How do I adjust TableRow cell widths within a TableLayout programmaticallly?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, tablerow

**Problem:** When I select a file with a long path or name, it forces adjacent columns to disappear.

The layout xml just positions the `TableLayout` as a placeholder in the `Activity` and Java code is used to create the `TableRows and views as necessary.

**What I'm trying to do:** A user can click an "Add" button to select a file on their phone to be added as a path and file name to a `TableRow` within a `TableLayout`. The first column has a button ( - ) to optionally remove the newly added TableRow, and the second column contains the path and file name.

**What I have tried:** I feel that I have tried everything programmatically adjusting various `LayoutParams` and either `Button` or `TextView` width and height parameter to set a fixed width... at least for the button. But nothing seems to work. When I search here for a programming example, it is always the layout XML code, not the Java.

I'm still kind of learning the Android but I'm stuck on this and thought someone may be able to point me in the right direction. Below are some images and the code that creates the TableRows and views within. Feel kind of stupid I can't figure this out.

**Before adding**

[image: before adding]

**After adding**

[image: after adding]

**Code** methods within a singleton class that create the `Button` and `TextView` views to the `TableRow` and `TableLayout`. The first method calls to the other two which create the Button ad TextView

```
public static TableRow setupFilesTableRow(Context context, TableLayout table, String fileID, String fileName, boolean header) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
        if(header) {
            row.addView(setupFilesAddRowButton(context, table));
            row.addView(addRowTextViewToTable(context, fileName, true));
        }else{
            row.addView(setupDeleteRowButton(context, table));

            for(int r=1; r < 2; r++){
                
                row.addView(addRowTextViewToTable(context, fileName, false));
                row.setClickable(true);
            }
        }
        return row;
    }
```

---

```
public static Button setupDeleteRowButton(Context context, TableLayout table){
        Button btnDelete = new Button(context);
        TableRow.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        trLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
        btnDelete.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        btnDelete.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
        btnDelete.setText("-");
        btnDelete.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD);
        btnDelete.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        btnDelete.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            deleteTableRows(table);
        });
        return btnDelete;
    }
```

---

```
public static TextView addRowTextViewToTable(Context context, String value, boolean bold){

        TextView tv;
        tv = new TextView(context);
        TableRow.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();

        trLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        if(bold) tv.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        tv.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
        tv.setTextSize(12);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        return tv;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I learned to use the term "dynamic" instead of "programmatic", I was able to find some help, and as a result, resolved my issue. The following link provided the basis for me to infer a solution to my issue. Below the link is my solution in answer to this question.

Inspired source:
http://mangoprojects.info/android-2/creating-a-tablelayout-dynamically-in-android/

**Solution:** I failed to apply `LayoutParams` at the declaration of the `TableRow`. Once I added these parameters, I could use `TableRow.LayoutParams` to help define and control the individual `Button` and `TextViews` using `.weight` and `.height` parameters in my particular case. See the updated code and pic of the results.

**Visual Result of Code Update**

[image: Result]

**Code Updates to `setupFilesTableRow`**

```
    TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(ll);
```

**Code Updates to `setupDeleteRowButton`** (adding a weight and height helped)

```
    Button btnDelete = new Button(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    trLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
    trLayoutParams.weight = 1;
    trLayoutParams.height =75;
    btnDelete.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
```

**Code Updates to `addRowTextViewToTable`***

```
    TextView tv;
    tv = new TextView(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    trLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
    trLayoutParams.weight = 5;
    tv.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
```